# Electrons and Positrons: What happens when a positron beam in-phase with diffracted electrons is used to make a hologram with the anti-electrons?

Tags: electrons, diffraction, antimatter, hologram

Suppose two independent beams of positrons and electrons are filtered such that each is in phase with the other **(correction: this probably isn't possible, although terminology to this effect is out there on google)**.

Next, allow the positrons to be idled and sent across some target zone in a wave loop of mirrors that is powered from a source of positrons. **(correction: this is an unclear and unnecessary detail -- just assume the means to procure a constant positron reference beam is available**).

Finally, take the electron beam and diffract it through a **(correction: double-)** slit so that it hits some object -- like an apple.

Proceed to allow the reflected electrons (coming off the apple) to arrive at the target zone where coherent positrons (anti-electrons) are passing.

Would the positrons and electrons annihilate in the form of a gamma-ray hologram that goes shooting off somewhere, or would they merely super-impose (because waves cannot interact with each-other)?

---

Update

I.e. would the beams diffract each other (thus behaving in a manner fundamentally different than the individual particles) due to the indeterminacy (**which was intended by my thought experiment, but perhaps was not possible or did not occur**)

But, it turns out my question was a double question, and the answer accepted below answered the question I asked in the lead up to the one intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer is in three parts: the first part tries to correct some misconceptions apparently held by the OP, the second part describes a modification of the OP's proposed experiment that could, in principle, work; and the third part describes an experiment that has actually been done and may support the OP's idea, though a bit obliquely.

Part 1: Misconceptions

> Suppose two independent beams of positrons and electrons are filtered
> such that each is in phase with the other.

It is not possible to filter two independent laser beams to put them in phase with each other; and it is even less possible to filter two particle beams to put them in phase with each other.  However, having your positron and electron beams in phase is not necessary.  What's necessary is for the positrons all to have the same momentum so they will all have the same wavelength.  Ideally the same will be true of the electrons, but the conditions aren't quite so stringent: a properly made optical hologram can be reconstructed with light having a wide range of frequencies, and the same would be true of a "matter wave" hologram reconstructed by another "matter wave" beam.

> Next, allow the positrons to be idled and sent across some target zone
> in a wave loop of mirrors that is powered from a source of positrons.

It's not at all clear what you mean by "idled", or "wave loop of mirrors".

> Finally, take the electron beam and diffract it through a slit so that
> it hits some object -- like an apple.

> Proceed to allow the reflected electrons (coming off the apple) to
> arrive at the target zone where coherent positrons (anti-electrons)
> are passing.

Here you are apparently intending to use the positron beam as a reference beam and the electron beam, modified by interacting with an object, as an object beam.  The problem with this is that the positrons and electrons will not interfere, even if they have the same wavelengths, because there is no uncertainty about *where they came from*.  That uncertainty is a prerequisite for interference in the double slit interferometer and all other interferometers-- and a hologram *is the output of an interferometer*.

> Would the positrons and electrons annihilate in the form of a
> gamma-ray hologram that goes shooting off somewhere, or would they
> merely super-impose (because waves cannot interact with each-other)?

As described in the question, the answer is that no hologram would be formed. Some of the positrons and electrons might annihilate, but there would be nothing to constrain the resulting gamma rays to travel in any particular direction(s) and form an image.

Part 2: An experiment that could in principle work

**HOWEVER**, if single positrons were used to provide both object and reference beam (by splitting the positron's wave function, passing part of it through the object, then causing the unmodified part to overlap with the object-modified part), it would be possible to form a *positron* interference pattern that could, in principle, act as a hologram and be used to reconstruct an image of the object (single particle) "beam".  Reconstruction would involve "illuminating" the "hologram" with another beam of particles, capable of interacting with positrons, at precisely the same angle as the reference beam. If the illumination beam were also single particles, maybe by a long stretch of the imagination it might be possible to get the electron "beam" to be diffracted by the positron "hologram", but in any practical sense it would not be possible in an experimental setup that could be built with today's technology and completed in a human lifetime.

But the OP is asking something fundamentally different, which is actually a very interesting question.  I'll take the liberty of restating the question in a less specific way: "*Can a hologram composed of substance A be illuminated by radiation B that interacts with substance A to produce radiation C, such that radiation C reconstructs an image stored in the hologram?*"

Oddly enough, the answer is "yes".  I've done it. I formed a focused-image hologram of a 3D rose (about 25 mm in x, y, and z) in a sheet of photopolymer about 1 mm thick.  In that particular photopolymer, the resulting regions of high and low refractive index turned out also to be regions of high and low fluorescence when illuminated by green light.  The emitted fluorescence was a rather broadband red. When I illuminated the hologram with green light at the reference angle, a red 3D rose, slightly blurry, was easily visible in the photopolymer. I've never sat down and done the calculations to be sure why that red image formed, but I'm pretty sure it is related to the way "[photonic crystals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photonic_crystal)",  X-ray diffraction and electron diffraction work: the spatial structure of the hologram only allows waves having certain wavelengths and directions to propagate.

A vaguely related experiment using optically formed holograms to diffract neutrons is described [here](https://www.mdpi.com/1996-1944/5/12/2788/htm).  Probably something very similar could be done for low-energy x-rays or electrons.  The interatomic spacing in solids, on the order of a tenth of a nanometer, is large compared to the wavelength of even a low-energy gamma ray (a hundredth of a nanometer), so it would be very difficult to make a useful gamma-ray diffracting hologram.

Comment: in the case of "idled" or an "idler beam", the idea was to use the same language you can find in modern optics papers and articles regarding quantum radar and other constructs where a beam is split at the source, with one half sent to bounce off a distant object, and the other used as a reference beam -- but not in the holographic sense.  Instead, it is meant in the sense of quantum-entanglement.  The entangled, idler beam is used to filter the photons returning or something along those lines.  So I picked up the idea of "idling" a beam from there.

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/288545614_A_New_Radar_System_based_on_Entangled_Photonic_Beam

Comment: Anyways, I am taking the term at face value: if you pass a beam through a loop -- two or more mirrors that reflect the beam around a distance, you can effectively have a beam "sit around" or "idle." For example, the Michelson Morley setup, or any other setup.  I more or less put it in there to test fire the "**idle**" term.  Now I know that it is not going to be interpreted in a general, **solution neutral** manner ‍♂️

Comment: **phase filters** appear to be a relatively new concept (1993)... but I'll read through this and your answer and modify accordingly -- I didn't anticipate that part of my answer being a problem https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/003040189390238Z

Comment: I don't know what these guys are doing (**Bessel waves!?**) but it seems like manipulating laser beams (and not just incoherent light) by phase is an open question, anyhow http://soreq.gov.il/mmg/eng/Documents/Optical%20phase%20shaping%20filter.pdf

Comment: ... and modified the question in a best effort to match your response and these comments.  The idea of a dichroic hologram is fascinating.

Comment: And I'll study this paper so that maybe I can level more coherent questions going forward.  Do you know the "original" hologram paper that would have been the root paper of the field?

Comment: for example, http://people.math.harvard.edu/~ctm/home/text/others/shannon/entropy/entropy.pdf  this is the root paper of "machine learning", published just after WW2 was ended.

Comment: The original paper on holography was by Denis Gabor: https://www.nature.com/articles/Art56

Comment: Thanks man.  Will study that and upgrade my follow up q's.  Also, on any new concepts or terms, I'll include the paper or article I am pulling it from.  As a disclaimer, never had any background in this stuff -- to be blunt, it was difficult to become aware that holography and advanced optics are "worth knowing about"... as I've come to understand it, a lot of people's careers were wiped out when the holographic disc (after blu ray) died.